# Developing Between Multiple Computers

Tags: git, github, workflow

I've been using Git for version control and GitHub for publishing code for a little while now. I'm getting comfortable with the interface and find it very helpful. However, I'm a bit torn with this situation. I'm a student using my school computers and personal computer to write code.

I have to frequently work on my application from multiple computers. I could be in the middle of writing code when the period ends and I need to leave. It feels wrong to push the code up to GitHub then sync the remote branch with my PC when I get home (this means that'd I'd have daily pushes to GitHub.) However, is this correct usage? If not, what tool should I use? I want to sync multiple workspaces together with code that could very well be incorrect and buggy.

Comment: What makes this "feel wrong" to you? Do you not want to see "work in progress" commits in you history, are you only using a single branch and want it to always be in a working state?

Comment: So have a WIP branch and just force-push over it.  Git's a full history editor, you can rewrite and revise as you like, there's nothing sacred about a commit.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to push as soon as you target a work in progress branch.

Later on you can ammend or squash the history of that branch before merging with other main branches.

Take a look at this: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following ,

Create a branch called `school_work` and work on that. At the end of the day pushout your changes to `develop`. 
Remember we will be using `develop` as the branch that has the `holy` code.
When you reach home checkout the `school_work`  branch and continue where you left off.
At the end of the work.
Do a `git rebase -i ...` to do a interactive revase wherein you organize your commits the way you want them to look like.
At the end do a `git pull --rebase origin develop` . This will rebase your branch against develop.

Now merge your `school_work` branch into `develop`.

At the next school work session checkout a new branch called `school_work2` from the then `develop` and repeat the steps.